# Background image not being displayed in server(production) generated pdf

Tags: reactjs, express, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to generate a pdf. The backend is express the front end is react. Everything works well on localhost. The pdf generated, is basically perfect. However, the issues start when I deploy my application. When I generate a pdf on the deployed application, the main background image at the top of the pdf(page one) does not display. What could be the issue?

Here is the backend code;

```
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.setContent(myHtml);
          await page.emulateMedia('screen');
          const buffer = await page.pdf({
            format: "A4",
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
              left: "0px",
              top: "0px",
              right: "0px",
              bottom: "0px"
            }
          });
          await browser.close();
          res.end(buffer);
```

Here is the front end code;

```
    this.setState({downloadButtonLoading: true}, () => {
      axios.get(
        url, {
            responseType: 'blob'
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        const FileDownload = require('js-file-download');
        this.setState({downloadButtonLoading: false})
        FileDownload(res.data, 'pdfname.pdf');

      }).catch((error) => {
        this.setState({downloadButtonLoading: false})
        console.log(error)
      })

    })

  }
```

Comment: For verification, did you try downloading the generated file manually without using React? I suspect the issue is the difference in your local and deployment environment which is affecting Puppeteer.

Comment: Yes, I tried with a normal html link and url.